# C# Process WaitForExit hangs when starting python

Tags: c#, python

I use a `Process` class to start Python like below (in a thread):

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "python.exe";
info.Arguments = "test.py";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = info;
p.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.RedirectStandardError = true;
...
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

when Python ends with errors (the python process is no longer showing in Windows Task Manager), WaitForExit still hangs. However, if I use `IronPython` instead, it works fine. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: Please see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#links) to learn how to link to the 'separate thread' that you speak of. It might make have useful info for people trying to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. Redirects and ErrorDataReceived/OutputDataReceived event implements causes this problem, use Redirects and StreamReader instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing python.exe to pythonw.exe